# how to access Pre populated database directly from apk?

Tags: android, sqlite, memory

I have pre populated database of around 25 MB, which needs to be copied from assets folder to data/data/packagename/ to access database from code.

My issue is when I shift apk file from phone memory to sd card, it gives following information:

```
Total storage used: 27.54Mb
Application: 892Kb
Data: 26.67Mb
```

And If I run application, database is copied from apk file(from assets folder) to specified path in internal phone memory, and database is so large that device get slower. and ultimately there is duplication of database, one is in phone memory and one is in apk file which is on sdcard.

So my question is Can I access pre populated database directly from apk file without copying to any other place? Please help me.

NOTE: I have split database into 26 parts as assets folder does not take file >1.5 MB. so I needed to split entire database.

Comment: Is it possible to use this database as remote?

Comment: no, as this database is changed on regular basis from remote database and it will increase in size periodically.

Comment: I was developing app like you do, huge db, and then talked to one software engineer on android, he said that cheaper and better for the phone is to have remote db. You still gather data from another db, you can create your db again as remote and it still recieve gathered data. This is just an idea. And for your question you cannot populate directly from the apk file unless you don't write it somewhere or hold it in memory..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I access pre populated database directly from apk file without copying to any other place?

No, sorry.

Comment: so do I have last option to copy database from assets folder to sdcard (I do not want to store database in phone memory as size may increase in future)  and access from there? If yes, I am worried that anyone can access that database by mounting sdcard.

Comment: @Jignesh Brahmkhatri: "so do I have last option to copy database from assets folder to sdcard" -- sure. "If yes, I am worried that anyone can access that database by mounting sdcard." -- users can access your database regardless of where you store it. If users are not supposed to access the database, do not have the database on the device.

Comment: But can I apply any encryption, that after opening app, database will be decrypted and after closing app, database will be encrypted?

Comment: @Jignesh Brahmkhatri: Only if you do that yourself. It will not help, as anyone will be able to get at your encryption algorithm and keys.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I will look into it, but for me, now it is not possible to move again to remote server. I need to copy database into sdcard now as per client's requirement.